# Django forms are not being processed with POST request

Tags: django, post, get

I have written the most basic Django application to understand forms as below. When I enter the required data into the fields and press Submit, the code after "if request.method == 'POST'" is ignored. I am redirected to the appropriate page and an entry with the first name "John" and last name "Smith" is created in my database. As you can see in the code below, this object should only be created if the request method is not POST. I know that I have set the request method to POST because that is what is shown on my CMD so what is happening??

Here is my template 'index.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to the site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="thanks/" method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" vlaue="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import NewObjectForm
from .models import Object

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=NewObjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            a=Object.create(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
            a.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            new=Object.create(first_name="Not",last_name="Valid")
            new.save()
    else:
        #Code which is run if the request.method is not equal to 'POST'
        form=NewObjectForm()
        newer=Object.objects.create(first_name="John",last_name="Smith")
        newer.save()
    return render(request,'formapp/index.html',{'form':form})

def end(request):
    return render(request,'formapp/thanks.html')
```

Here is the urls.py file from the main project:

```
"""experimentalForms URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('formapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And here is the urls.py file from my application:

```
'''
URLs for formapp
'''
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name="formapp"

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('thanks/',views.end),
]
```

Comment: show us your URLs

Comment: Thanks @iklinac! I have now included copies of both my url files. Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: index is never called when you press the button.

Comment: @mbieren thank you for your input! Why should I be calling index? My aim was to load the form when the website was accessed, take the data from the form and redirect the user to the thank you page when they pressed the button. The index is loaded correctly when the website loads and the redirect happens as expected. Thanks again

Comment: the form action "thanks" is processed when the form is submitted by the button. Your code is never called

Comment: check this out. : https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/django/simple-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mbieren! I have changed my the action attribute of my form and it is working perfectly!